# Hibernate collections not populated when running from IntelliJ idea

Tags: hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I have spring boot app with Hibernate. IDE IntelliJ idea 2018.3 but the problem is proven to happen with all versions up to 2019.3.4

Steps to reproduce are not entirely deterministic but it goes something like:

1. Build app with maven from command-line
2. Start the app from IntelliJ Idea
3. In the code select entity with child collection, print out its items - collection contains few - expected
4. *Non-deterministic step*: restart app, rebuild app from IntelliJ menu, repeat several times
5. Start the app again
6. Select same entity with child collection, print out its items - items are now empty, no error is thrown - *unexpected*

There are clear steps to fix:

1. Clear Idea caches/restart
2. `mvn clean package` project from command-line
3. Restart the app
4. Now loaded entity contains items again

Observation:

1. Never happened when running *outside* of IntelliJ idea, i.e. deployed to real environment

This makes me think it is somehow related to the fact that it is running in IntelliJ.

What I tried:

1. Debugger - went up to the point when DB query is executed and the query is correct and contains even the collection items. There are just not populated into the collection when processing the result.
2. Even though it is not easy code to debug I *think* the collection population gets skipped on condition similar to `isEnhancedForLazyLoading()` which made me think it could be related to proxies and byte-code manipulation (?)

I'm looking for insights on what could be the difference between building classes with Maven from command-line comparing to building the project in IntelliJ especially regarding to Hibernate classes and proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a side effect of lazy loading, probably when implemented via byte code enhancement.

If I understand you correctly you use the debugger to inspect properties of a JPA entity. 
In order to implement lazy loading and dirty checking JPA implementations need to get code between the code you write for your entities and the code using these entities.

To verify this hunch and further clarify what *exactly* is happening and when you'd probably need to read up on the conditions for byte code enhancement in Hibernate.

There are two variants how they do this:

1. Proxies: You don't get entities back, but proxies which behave like the entity (more or less) but also take care of lazy loading. This can lead among other things like casts to fail some of the time, depending on how the entity was loaded.
2. Byte code manipulation: Some extra byte code is injected into the entity class in order to take care of lazy loading and so on. AFAIK this typically happens when the class gets loaded, i.e. the byte code in the file system is unchanged, but the JVM actually executes a manipulated version of it. This means the byte code does not match the code seen by the IDE and the IDE doesn't know about it, since it checks the byte code on the file system matches the source code and would produce a warning if the two don't match.

I suspect when the code gets compiled and executed via Maven the second variant is used but if it gets compiled/run by the IDE the first variant is used, resulting in this confusing and changing behavior.

I suggest using the getters and the [variants of "evaluate expression"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/examining-suspended-program.html#evaluating-expressions) to inspect the properties of your entities.

Comment: It seems that is indeed the case, some developer added maven hibernate enhance plugin so it probably really mixed up things, will verify and potentially approve